# BatchedBridge error in React Native on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a simple native iOS app that I want to integrate React Native into. When I open the view controller, I get an error:

```
> Error calling RCTLog.logIfNoNativeHook
> 
> Unhandled JS Exception: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your
> bundle is packaged correctly
> 
> RCTFatal
> -[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]
> __34-[RCTCxxBridge _initializeBridge:]_block_invoke facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::tryFunc(std::__1::function<void ()>
> const&)
> facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_1::operator()() const void
> std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void>::__call<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_1&>(facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_1&&&)
> std::__1::__function::__func<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_1,
> std::__1::allocator<facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runOnQueue(std::__1::function<void
> ()>&&)::$_1>, void ()>::operator()() std::__1::function<void
> ()>::operator()() const invocation function for block in
> facebook::react::RCTMessageThread::runAsync(std::__1::function<void
> ()>)
> __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
> __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
> __CFRunLoopRun CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop]
> __NSThread__start__
> _pthread_body
> _pthread_body thread_start
```

This is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'NativeRNTest' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    'BatchedBridge',
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod "yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'GLog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Pods for NativeRNTest

  target 'NativeRNTestTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'NativeRNTestUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

My environment:

```
>react-native info
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/[redacted]/Projects/native_rn_demo/node_modules (5ms)

Environment:

  OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
  Node: 8.9.0
  Yarn: 1.1.0
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 2.3 AI-162.4069837

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: ^16.0.0 => 16.0.0
  react-native: ^0.51.0 => 0.51.0
```

I've searched for this problem, and all the solutions are for Android, and don't seem to work here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I fixed the error by renaming `index.js` to `index.ios.js`.

Comment: Hi @Macondo2Seattle, having upgrading my project from RN 0.39 to 0.52 (yeah I know), I'm having the exact same problem as you above : Error calling RCTLog.logIfNoNativeHook. I tried to change index.js to index.ios.js but didn't fixed a thing. Did you happen to do something else than that to fix this error? I can't find a thing about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GuillaumeS. I had the same stuff and just solved it by having all files index.js, index.android.js and index.ios.js. Try it out and comment if it helped.

Comment: @GuillaumeS. renaming the file was all I had to do, as far as I remember.

Comment: still encounter this issue with rn 0.55.4 after remove node_modules and resintall. Any fix?

Answer (score 2):

That's how I resolved it.

Terminate your metro bundler > react-native link > react-native run-ios

It was not bundling because of some errors which are not showing in the simulator but just bundling was failed. After I re-bundled the package from starting it resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

For my case I forgot to shut down my metro bundler so when I quit that terminal window and rebuilt project it worked all fine.